# How do I use a for loop to retrieve from the user the indicated number of items indicated?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
int a = 1;
printf("Enter the number of items from 1 and 10: \n");
while (a <= 10)
{
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a >= 1 && a <= 10)
    {
        printf("Thank You!\n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong input! Try Again.\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

To be more detailed about what I'm asking lets say that the user enters 3 (for 3 items) how would I use the for loop to retrieve that information so I can further finish the code.

Comment: retrieve information using `for..loop` why ? it already in `a`. might be you run for loop like `for(int i=0;i<a;i++){ //do somthing}` in your valid input `if` statement inside `while...loop`.

Comment: im supposed to use a for loop to retrieve a and use a while loop to ask for prices for whatever a is; so if a is 5 then i have to use a while loop to ask for prices for 5 items

Comment: @user3308912 can't get you? you got me :)?

Comment: What u want actually?

Comment: change `while (a <= 10)` to `while (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind following points:

- Get the no.of choice before starting loop
- Check the condition in loop with no. of choices.
- Only one loop is enough for your task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
int a = 1;
    bool bFlag = true;
    int price[10];
    printf("Enter the number of items from 1 and 10: \n");
    while(bFlag){
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a >= 1 && a <= 10)
    {
         printf("Thank You!\n");
         break;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong input! Try Again.\n");
        continue;
    }
    }

for (int i = 0; i< a; i++)
{
 printf("Enter price for item %d = ", i); 
 scanf("%d",&price[i]);
}
```